# peer_method in symfony's admin generator

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have a symfony module for my `GenericImport` class. Rather than the default method symfony uses for the list page, I want to use `GenericImportTable::getQueue()`. I thought the following would work but it didn't:

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:
  list:
    peer_method: getQueue
```

How can I use a custom query for the list page? (I'm using Doctrine.)

(To be clear, I don't wish to manually create a whole new custom action. I'm going the route I'm going because I want to take advantage of everything that comes with the admin generator like batch actions, the filter, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try table_method.

...and read more here: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12#chapter_12_sub_table_method